# Using matplotlib with Qt5 backend with an existing QApplication running, in the same process

Tags: matplotlib, pyside2

We have a Qt5 application that uses PySide2. Recently, we wanted to show plots using matplotlib while our PySide2 application is running in the same process (in a different thread) but then matplotlib crashes (when using PySide2) or freezes before drawing (when using PyQt5).

Here is a minimal sample, uncomment the 23rd line to make matplotlib crash or freeze:

```
from threading import Thread

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def start_qt_app():
    t = Thread(target=qt_app_thread_func)
    t.start()


def qt_app_thread_func():
    app = QApplication()
    label = QLabel("Hello World")
    label.show()
    app.exec_()


# Uncomment the line below to make matplotlib crash.
#start_qt_app()

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.show()

input("Press enter to quit.")

print("Finished.")
```

My guess is that this is related to the limitation that we can only have 1 QApplication running in a process. So this causes something to go wrong in matplotlib.

How can I solve this problem? One solution that comes to my mind is to create a proxy object for matplotlib that runs matplotlib in another process but I am not sure if this would be the least labor intensive solution. Maybe I can somehow make matplotlib use the existing QApplication? I cannot run our PySide2 app in another process since it uses dynamically created numpy arrays to be passed from main thread to the GUI, and it would cost performance to start it in another process.

Comment: Matplotlib, just as any other GUI must run in the main thread.

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501454/show-progressbar-in-qt-with-computationally-heavy-background-process/59612934?noredirect=1#comment105409977_59612934

Answer (score 1):

As [`@ImportanceOfBeingErnest`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest) points out, matplotlib can live with Qt as the official example shows: [Embedding in Qt](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html).

Example:

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()

    label = QLabel("Hello World")
    label.show()

    canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
    ax = canvas.figure.subplots()
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

    canvas.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use asyncqt to manage ui and application threads.from asyncqt QEventLoop is a way you can accomplish with

```
await loop.run_in_executor(exec, method_name)
```

asyncqt is a spin off library from quamash which is written for PyQt5. example codes are same. So upon your preference, you may use asyncqt with PySide2 or quamash with PyQt5 to make your app responsive when background tasks are running.

[asyncqt examples](https://github.com/gmarull/asyncqt/blob/master/examples/executor_example.py)

[asyncqt 0.7.0 pypi](https://pypi.org/project/asyncqt/)

[Quamash 0.6.1](https://pypi.org/project/Quamash/)